# Diff and sort and extract first line of new file

Tags: linux, bash

I have two *csv* files. What I need to do is get the header of the new file and `diff` the two *csv* files irregardless of their sorting.

I have the following command

```
cat new-file.txt | 
bash -c "diff --new-file --speed-large-files \
--new-line-format=%L --old-line-format= \
--unchanged-group-format= \
<(sort <(tail -n+2 old-file.txt)) <(head -n 1 -; sort <(tail -n+2 -))"
```

Everything has to be inside the `bash -c` since I'm using some program the requires that. Also the *new-file.txt* needs to be piped.

The above command does not have the correct output, but when I use something like this:

```
cat new-file.txt | 
bash -c "diff --new-file --speed-large-files \
--new-line-format=%L --old-line-format= \
--unchanged-group-format= \
<(sort <(tail -n+2 old-file.txt)) <(sort <(tail -n+2 -))"
```

...then the output is correct except that the header line of the new file is not included in the output.

Comment: Why do you use `bash -c`? why not `cat file | diff ....`?

Comment: Because the program I use requires that the linux command should be inside bash -c

Comment: ? It makes no sense. Could be your current shell is not `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a program, the input descriptor is tied to that program. Because of how buffering works, utilities will read more then one line, sometimes the whole input, and in case of `head` output only the first line. Because of that, the next command will read usually nothing. The best and reliable way is to use the builtin `read` and `printf` commands (which sadly requires a bit more typing).

```
< new-file.txt diff ... <(IFS= read -r first_line; printf "%s\n" "$first_line"; the_rest)
# or
< new-file.txt diff ... <(IFS= read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; the_rest)
# or I usually do single char variable
< new-file.txt diff ... <(IFS= read -r l; printf "%s\n" "$l"; the_rest)
```

Your command would look like:

```
< new-file.txt bash -c "diff --new-file --speed-large-files --new-line-format=%L --old-line-format= --unchanged-group-format= <(sort <(tail -n+2 old-file.txt)) <(IFS= read -r l; do printf \"%s\\n\" \"\$l\"; sort <(tail -n+2 -))"
# or
< new-file.txt bash -c 'diff --new-file --speed-large-files --new-line-format=%L --old-line-format= --unchanged-group-format= <(sort <(tail -n+2 old-file.txt)) <(IFS= read -r l; do printf "%s\n" "$l"; sort <(tail -n+2 -))'
```

Comment: I tried your command but sadly, it did not work. The lines I got were not the expected output. This is the command i used:
cat new-file.txt | bash -c "diff --new-file --speed-large-files --new-line-format=%L --old-line-format= --unchanged-group-format= <(sort <(tail -n+2 old-file.txt)) <(IFS= read -r l; printf "%s\n" "$l"; sort <(tail -n+2 -))"

Comment: Because you are in double quotes, `$l` is expanded..... Also `"` are not preserved, because they end one quoting and start another.... Please take your time to learn about properly quoting, and in the meantime prefer to use single quotes when passing script argument to a subshell, like `bash -c 'echo "properly quoted argument"'`.

Comment: I tried that and it did include the header on the output, but the diff command was not able to detect all the changes vs when I'm just sorting the two files without the header

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the very last process substitution:

```
 <(head -n 1 -; sort <(tail -n+2 -))"
```

...to:

```
 <( tee >(head -n 1)  >(sleep .1; sort <(tail -n+2 -)) > /dev/null )"
```